# Replace one ViewController in TabbarController with NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I noticed in Whatsapp there are four tabs. If you disable the access to Contacts, the view in first tab, Favorites, will be replaced with the information view which will guide user to open the Settings.

I was trying to copy this function with following codes (in AppDelegate):

```
let gotoSettingsVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("gotoSettingsViewController") as! GotoSettingsViewController
let tabbarController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController! as! UITabBarController

gotoSettingsVC.tabBarItem = tabbarController.tabBar.selectedItem
tabbarController.viewControllers![tabbarController.selectedIndex] = gotoSettingsVC
```

The gotoSettingsVC can be shown correct but without Navigation Bar. How to show this View with a Navigation Bar like the normal View in tabbarController?

thank you for any help.

Comment: You are aware that beyond explaining how to change settings, you can now actually give them a button to tap and it will take them to settings.

Comment: Hi ryantxr, this is what I was trying to do. My codes detects the settings for Contacts access, if set to No, I want to show a new View Controller to tell them the reason for the access, and then give them a button to open the settings. Alert ViewController works in this way but too ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the `GotoSettingsViewController` in a navigation controller, and set that as one of the tabBar controllers view controller.

Comment: Sorry but can you please give me some example codes...... My codes above is just put GotoSettingsViewController into tabBar controller's view controller array.

Comment: How about [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)?